# Bluetooth connectivity in QT4?

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth, qt4

I'm trying to write an application in QT4 that uses Bluetooth. The application is for a Desktop machine and will be run on a Linux operating system. What is the best way of doing this? Does the QT4 SDK have bluetooth support built in? (I've read something about QT Mobility?) If not, can anyone recommend an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.bluez.org/

That is all.